# Call function in function from another class PHP

Tags: php, class, function, abstract

I have read a few threads about abstract class here at Stackoverflow and I think it's what I need, but I can't get the declaration straight.

What I want to do is to call a **function2** (in classB) **in a function1** (in classA).

How should I do this?

Comment: Needs more info - do you have an initialized instance of classB in classA?

Comment: If you aren't accessing any data members from that class, make the function `static`. Then you can call it using: `MyClass::myFunction`.

Answer (score 17):

If you only need to access ClassB's method from ClassA but don't need a parent-child relationship between the two, a static method may be more appropriate:

```
class ClassA
{
  public function method1() {
    echo ClassB::method2();
  }
}

class ClassB
{
  public static function method2() {
    return 'WOOT!';
  }
}

$cls_a = new ClassA();
$cls_a->method1();

// or alternatively, you don't even need to instantiate ClassA
echo ClassB::method2();
```

Comment: useful info. Thanks for the methods.

Comment: What if the class is in a different directory?

Comment: from PHP 5.4 you should use `(new ClassName)->method();`