# How to call another class function in PHP

Tags: php, class, function

My question is similar to [Call function in function from another class PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420431/call-function-in-function-from-another-class-php), but its answer does not work for me.

Basically here is what I want to do.

in 'a.php', I defined class A.

```
class A{
  function ab(){}
  function cd(){}
  function ef(){}
  ...
}
```

in 'b.php', I would like to define class B that can call the function in class A.  Here is what I put, but it seems not work.

```
class B{
  function xy(){
    require 'a.php';
    $a = new A();
    $this->x = $a->ab();
    $this->y = $a->cd();
    return $a->ef();
  }
}
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction?  Thanks

========

UPDATE: to make my question more clear I made another example.

```
class Person{
  function firstName(){return $this->firstName;}
  function lastName() {return $this->lastName;}
  function address()  {return $this->address;}
  ...
}

class Car{
  function ownerInfo(){
     $owner = array();
     require 'person.php';
     $p = new Person($this->ownerID);
     $owner['firstname'] = $p->firstName();
     $owner['lastname']  = $p->lastName();
     $owner['address']   = $p->address();
     //I am sure the data is there, but it returns nothing here
     return $owner;  
  }
}
```

Comment: Inheritance?....Just extend `class B` to `class A` and you can use those methods defined in `class A`

Comment: extend the class B with class A

Comment: not sure for php but i know that in c++ you include (require) the file in the header (well the beginning of the file, or before the class B deceleration)

Comment: actually A and B are different model so I don't want to use "class B extends A".  Most the other functions in A and B are not related.

Comment: I tried to put the require statement in the beginning of the file but it does not work either.

Comment: it seems that none of the $a->function() return any value if you use $b= new B(), then $b->xy();

Comment: In your code sample, all of `A`'s methods have an empty body, so they return `null` by default.

Comment: no...i just try to make it simply so I did not copy & paste all the code within these functions...actually they did return the expected value when you use them outside the class B.  Just does not work within a function in class B.

Comment: That makes no sense. You will probably have to give more details about what `A` actually does.

Comment: I added another example, hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
class B extends A{
  function xy(){
    require 'a.php';
    $a = new A();
    $this->x = $a->ab();
    $this->y = $a->cd();
    return $a->ef();
  }
}
```

Comment: Ofcourse its not good but we can use like this right because it may extract a.php file whenever this class B is used,orelse it may decrese to load a.php which unvaluable..??

Comment: is there any other way to do that? actually I already put "class A extends C" and "class B extends D"

Comment: Adding the `extends A` does nothing. It only adds to code confusion.

Comment: @coolmoon you can do like this and there is NP if you extend others to others